# hunchentoot define-easy-handler with ssl?

Tags: ssl, common-lisp, hunchentoot

I use define-easy-handler all the time. I now have a freshly minted ssl certificate and associated pem files, but can't figure out what the ssl equivalent of d-e-h is.

For example, I have:

```
  (hunchentoot:define-easy-handler 
   (login :uri "/login") 
   () 
   (login-html))
```

which is just a simple form whose formaction goes here:

```
(hunchentoot:define-easy-handler 
   (dologin :uri "/dologin") 
   (email password) 
   (dologin-html email password))
```

I got the required `.pem` files from freecert, so I think that I have the files that go to :**SSL-CERTIFICATE-FILE** and :**SSL-PRIVATEKEY-FILE**. I've tried various args to the above to make this work, but can't seem to get it to work. Can someone give me an example of how to do this?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: There should be an easy-ssl-acceptor class according to the doc (http://quickref.common-lisp.net/hunchentoot.html#go-to-the-HUNCHENTOOT_003ccolon_003e_003ccolon_003eEASY_002dSSL_002dACCEPTOR-class). Use this class to instanciate your acceptor. Since define-easy-handler is handled by the easy-acceptor superclass, it should work (I can't test right now)

Comment: @coredump: why not make that an answer?

Comment: Yes, easy-ssl-acceptor is a class (HUNCHENTOOT:EASY-SSL-ACCEPTOR, Class: #<STANDARD-CLASS HUNCHENTOOT:EASY-SSL-ACCEPTOR>) that I can instantiate, but having been using d-e-h all this time, I don't have a mental model for how to make an acceptor "the hard way". (In part I'm confused by the names. D-E-H calls these handlers, and the rest of Huchentoot seems to call them acceptors. And, yes, they are both called "easy", but d-e-h doesn't seem to want to take :SSL arguments.) Can you offer some example code that does what you have in mind?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can keep your easy-handlers and change the type of acceptor you need.

```
(defpackage :web (:use :cl :hunchentoot))
(in-package :web)

;; This url can be accessed by all acceptors
(define-easy-handler (no-ssl :uri "/normal") ()
  (setf (content-type*) "text/plain")
  "NORMAL PAGE")

;; This url can be accessed only by an acceptor named SSL
(define-easy-handler (ssl :uri "/secure" :acceptor-names '(ssl)) ()
  (setf (content-type*) "text/plain")
  "SECURED PAGE")
```

**For tests**, if you don't already have a self-signed certificate , you can do:

```
$ cd /tmp
$ openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out server.crt -keyout server.key
```

Then, we define two kinds of acceptors:

```
(defvar *no-ssl-acceptor*
  (make-instance 'easy-acceptor :port 8080))

(defvar *ssl-acceptor*
  (make-instance 'easy-ssl-acceptor
                 :name 'ssl
                 :port 7777
                 :ssl-privatekey-file  #P"/tmp/server.key"
                 :ssl-certificate-file #P"/tmp/server.crt"))
```

Start them:

```
(start *ssl-acceptor*)
(start *no-ssl-acceptor*)
```

Your browser should complain the first time you try to access HTTPS pages (ignore the security exception).

- http://localhost:8080/normal
- http://localhost:8080/secure (should fail with 404)
- https://localhost:7777/normal
- https://localhost:7777/secure

Note also that the `:acceptor-names` argument is *optional* (thanks @Simeon Ikudabo), here above it was added explictly for the examples. You can just define an SSL acceptor and let all your pages be served over a secure link.

Comment: Yup. This works. Thanks! (Note for others, if you forget to put the S on https, as I initially did, you get a very obscure 1407609C error code.)

Comment: I know that this is old, but you don't need to define a name if you want each page to be ssl (which you should in 2019). You can simply create the easy-ssl-acceptor, and each of your easy-handlers will refer to that ssl server without needing to add the name slot-value.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a function of the handlers but of the acceptor.  All you need to do is use an `easy-ssl-acceptor` instead of an `easy-acceptor` for starting your server:

```
(hunchentoot:start (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-ssl-acceptor :port 4242))
```