# how fix error with hunchentoot ssl acceptor on clozure common lisp?

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot, clozure-cl

I tried to get an SSL version of hunchentoot running, on clozure common lisp 1.11.1 running on a MacBook Pro with OS 10.13.6

I started by creating certificates in the /tmp directory, as follows:

```
openssl req -new -x509 -nodes -out server.crt -keyout server.key
```

Here is my lisp code:

```
(ql:quickload "hunchentoot")

(in-package hunchentoot)

(define-easy-handler (test-ssl :uri "/secure") ()
  (setf (content-type*) "text/plain")
  "SECURED PAGE")

(defvar *ssl-acceptor*
  (make-instance 'easy-ssl-acceptor
    :port 7777
    :ssl-privatekey-file  #P"/tmp/server.key"
    :ssl-certificate-file #P"/tmp/server.crt"))

(start *ssl-acceptor*)
```

When I try to access `https://localhost:7777/secure` from my browser, nothing shows up on the browser, and hunchentoot throws the following error to the log window:

[image]

*Unhandled execption 11*, *Exception occurred while executing foreign code*

Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Comment: I’ve readof people who have used ssl in hunchentoot successfully in the past: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50749373/hunchentoot-define-easy-handler-with-ssl

Comment: I cannot reproduce this on Linux with the same version of CCL