# Redirect to https with hunchentoot

Tags: common-lisp, hunchentoot

I've set up a hunchentoot server with ssl. I'd like regular http requests to be redirected to https.

It seems like some combination of `hunchentoot:define-easy-handler` and `hunchentoot:redirect` is the way to go, but I can't figure it out.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(defvar *https-handler*
  (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-ssl-acceptor
                 :name 'ssl
                 :ssl-privatekey-file #P"/path/to/privkey.pem"
                 :ssl-certificate-file #P"/path/to/cert.pem"
                 :port 443))

(hunchentoot:start *https-handler*)
```

Comment: You need to set up an acceptor for port 80 as well. See this answer to another Hunchentoot question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50756148/2967

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can add simple http handler with redirect to ssl version:

```
(defvar *http-handler*
  (make-instance 'hunchentoot:easy-acceptor
                 :name 'http
                 :port 80))

(hunchentoot:define-easy-handler (redir-to-ssl :uri (lambda (uri) t) :acceptor-names '(http)) ()
  (hunchentoot:redirect "/" :protocol :https)) ; where magic happens
```

...and then start it too:

```
(hunchentoot:start *http-handler*)
```

This version redirects simply to index `/`.

Comment: Thank you! This is an acceptable solution for me, but is there any way to preserve the path? For example redirect `http://foo.org/stuff` -> `https://foo.org/stuff`?

Comment: @ark *"is there any way to preserve the path?"* I was always using only `define-easy-handler`. `(labda (uri) t)` is a function catching all URIs, but I don't see how this information can be passed down. But if you figure out, please share! :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, I am using the `hunchentoot:*dispatch-table*` directly. The way to redirect it independent of the path I discovered was to `hunchentoot:redirect` unless `(hunchentoot:ssl-p)` inside the handler. Most of my `defun`ed handlers are wrapped inside a macro for authenthentication. So, I merely had to modify that macro, and then `M-x slime-who-macroexpands` -> `C-c C-k`.

```lisp
(unless (hunchentoot:ssl-p)
  (hunchentoot:redirect (hunchentoot:request-uri*)
                       :protocol :https))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to indiscriminately redirect every HTTP request to HTTPS, using `easy-acceptor` is unnecessary. I'd suggest to define a specialized `acceptor`:

```
(defclass http-to-https-acceptor (hunchentoot:acceptor) ())
(defmethod hunchentoot:acceptor-dispatch-request ((acceptor http-to-https-acceptor) request)
  (hunchentoot:redirect (hunchentoot:request-uri request)
                        :protocol :https))
```

Then at some point:

```
(hunchentoot:start (make-instance 'http-to-https-acceptor :port 80))
```